# Android Gradle Build Resource.getIdentifier() always returns 0

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting started on porting my Game over to the new Gradle Build system for Android.
I'm using the Resource.getIdentifier() method to load some resources by name instead of ID. However, ever since switching to the Gradle build, this call always returns 0. The assets are included in the built jar, and the R.class in the dex file contains all of my resources and ID's as expected, so I am at a loss as to explain this. This code worked before I changed to the gradle build. My build.gradle is below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        }
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! my problem was that Resources.getIdentifer() takes 3 parameters, one of which is the package name. The debug section of my gradle script was tacking on ".debug" to the package name on the device. Solution is to remove the .debug suffix in the build.gradle.